# JS: any trick to hide source image url in canvas composition

Tags: canvas, yui

we are trying to build a canvas composition from 1-4 individual images, it there anyway to hide the source image URL so that end user cannot easily find the href of the individual original images from any traces (firebug etc)

see this page can hide the URL really well, any idea how did they do that? http://story.us/story?o=PBTbp8LMTYJ0

Comment: You can't really do this very well. Here's the URL for the first image on their page: http://app.story.us/story/media/102/43ccb099a52ab1ad/319d37bb2fdb4e25_large.jpg